# How can I pass multiple embeddings in my function?

Tags: programming, pennylane, kernel-methods, quantum-kernel

I have a problem with my code. I would like to try multiple embeddings in my kernel (I'm using the adjoint method). My idea is to pass them to the function and use them depending on what I pass. Unfortunately, it doesn't work as I think, or I can't program it. Help would be nice :)

Code:

```
from pennylane.templates import SqueezingEmbedding,QAOAEmbedding,IQPEmbedding,DisplacementEmbedding,AngleEmbedding, StronglyEntanglingLayers,BasisEmbedding,AmplitudeEmbedding,DisplacementEmbedding

def kernel_matrix(A, B):
    """Compute the matrix whose entries are the kernel
       evaluated on pairwise data from sets A and B."""
    
    kernel = np.array([[kernel(a, b) for b in B] for a in A]) #how can I pass on the method?
    return kernel


def Quantum_Kernel_pennylane(train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y, method):
   
    n_qubits = len(train_X[0])
    
    dev_kernel = qml.device('lightning.qubit', wires=n_qubits)
        
    projector = np.zeros((2**n_qubits, 2**n_qubits))
    projector[0, 0] = 1

    @qml.qnode(dev_kernel, interface="autograd")
    def kernel(x1, x2):
        """The quantum kernel.
           We use the adjoint method.
        """ 
        if method == qml.templates.embeddings.AmplitudeEmbedding:
            method(x1, wires=range(n_qubits), pad_with=0.4)  
            qml.adjoint(method)(x2, wires=range(n_qubits), pad_with=0.4)   
            return qml.expval(qml.Hermitian(projector, wires=range(n_qubits)))
        
        method(x1, wires=range(n_qubits))
        qml.adjoint(method)(x2, wires=range(n_qubits))   
        return qml.expval(qml.Hermitian(projector, wires=range(n_qubits)))
    
    svm = SVC(kernel=kernel_matrix).fit(train_X, train_y) # here is the problem how can I pass on the method?
    predictions = svm.predict(test_X)
    print(accuracy_score(predictions, test_y))





def main():
 methods = [IQPEmbedding,
           AngleEmbedding,
           AmplitudeEmbedding
          ]

 for method in methods:
    print(method)
    Quantum_Kernel_pennylane(train_X, test_X, train_y, test_y, method)# I want to pass on the Method
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a question about PennyLane, really? As you want the contents within the `Quantum_Kernel_pennylane` function to take the method into account when computing the kernel matrix, maybe you can define `kernel_matrix` in there?
Maybe it can be useful to look at the PennyLane [`qml.kernels` module](https://docs.pennylane.ai/en/stable/code/qml_kernels.html), where helper functions for kernel matrices etc are defined already? There also are associated code examples.